# Chracter deletion on reaching character limit or enable disable div on backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, html

We have a disabled div on reaching to maximum character limit, which is need to be enable on back space. But now we are not getting the ASCII code for back space in iPhone. How could i detect back space tap for div.  Here is my code for character limit in j Query and need to enable so that i can delete character:

```
<script>
var charlimit = 20;
var maindiv = 'content';
var charlendiv = 'myDiv';
$().ready(function()
   {
    var div = document.getElementById (maindiv);
    var text = $(div).text();
    document.getElementById(charlendiv).innerHTML = charlimit - text.length;
        $('#'+maindiv).keypress(function(e)
             { 
        var div = document.getElementById (maindiv);
            var text = $(div).text();
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (text.length < charlimit) 
             {
          div.contentEditable = true;
         }
        else
              {
           div.contentEditable = false;
           if(code=='08' || code=='46' || code=='')  //ASCII code not detect by keyboard back space
                {
             div.contentEditable = true;
             }
         }
    });
    $('#'+maindiv).keyup(function(e)
       {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        var div = document.getElementById (maindiv);
        var text = $(div).text();
        document.getElementById(charlendiv).innerHTML = charlimit - text.length;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code across multiple lines so as to make it easier to read

Comment: There you go. I've reformatted it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The div has been disabled so none of your key will work now. Better approach is not to disable the div, instead you can opt for changing color of the div when limit has reached.

Comment: but how to restrict user from further typing after limit has been reached.

Comment: actualy i am also inserting images also by commands document.execommand('insert')..something like this so how can i also prevent this?